# ListView empty when coming from other activity

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a class that extends a `SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Cursor cursor;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private int columnIndexRowID;
private int columnIndexFromAddrString;
private int columnIndexToAddrString;

public LastRequestsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.cursor = c;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.columnIndexRowID = c.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    this.columnIndexFromAddrString = c
            .getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_FROM_ADDR_STRING);
    this.columnIndexToAddrString = c
            .getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_TO_ADDR_STRING);

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView==null){

        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_last_request_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.id = -1;
        viewHolder.fromAddr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
        viewHolder.toAddr =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.to);
        viewHolder.arrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.last_request_arrow);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    viewHolder.id = this.cursor.getInt(columnIndexRowID);
    viewHolder.fromAddr.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.columnIndexFromAddrString));
    viewHolder.toAddr.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.columnIndexToAddrString));
    viewHolder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_alt);

    return convertView;

}

public class ViewHolder{
    public int id;
    public TextView fromAddr;
    public TextView toAddr;
    public ImageView arrow;
 }
}
```

It's used that way:

```
listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
            R.layout.main_activity_last_request_row, dbCursor,
            new String[] { MyDBAdapter.KEY_FROM_ADDR_STRING,
                    MyDBAdapter.KEY_TO_ADDR_STRING }, new int[] {
                    R.id.from, R.id.to }));
```

The list is created as expected. But: Sometimes the entries of this list seem to disappear (sometimes a few of them a still visible). This seems to happen each time, when I'm starting a new activity and (instantly) come back to this activity, e.g. changing to the home screen and then returning back to my activity. But, this happens only once: When switching again to the 'same other' activity and then come back, all list entries are still visible. 
I checked the list values and it seems like they're received correctly from the database but some kind of invisible.

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your getCount() Method

Comment: There's none. Is it necessary?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm sorry, I studied many tutorials but none of them could explain to me, what these different methods (getView, bindView, newView, getCount,...) , that need to be overwritten, really do. Could you briefly explain that to me, please? Or do you have a tutorial which points out those differences. P.S.: And as my list works - besides the above problem - I thought i don't need this method.

Comment: getView is the method which is similar to paint method in Applet, ok, getCount determines, how much datas are painted i.e., displayed in your ListView

Answer (score 0):

**getView is the method which is similar to paint method in Applet, ok, getCount determines, how much datas are painted i.e., displayed in your ListView**

**Specify the size of the List View in getCount() method and getItem{int pos), getItemId()**

```
public int getCount() {
    return array.length; 

// ForInstance i had an array 
//which contains 5 elements, i want that % elements in List, that's why i had specified the array.length here

}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far. As I'm using a cursor i need to return `cursor.getCount()`, right?! I did just a quick test: I seems to work for changing between activities, but I still have the same behavior of the list when I'm setting a header item of this list to `View.GONE` (and then `View.VISIBLE`). There must be another bug in my code... :(

Comment: Thanks! Any other ides what could cause this behavior?